# What microphone setup is best for recording 1-4 people?

Tags: microphone

I'm starting a video business that is shot inside a 10X10 tent. I will have ample time to set up sound and lights. Because the clientele will be rotating rather quickly, I have ruled lavs out. The people will all be facing the same direction on a bench. The question is : Should I use a couple of shotgun mics in an X pattern, or perhaps a condenser mic or two?

Comment: A matched pair of decent condenser mics in an XY stereo recording configuration should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I would use two cardioid condenser mics in a [ORTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORTF_stereo_technique) constellation. For recording speech is for me the best compromise between [ILD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization) and [ITD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization)

Comment: +1 for the idea. It could be improved by copying the definitions of ORTF, ILD AND ITD into the answer. Links alone are generally discouraged on the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one mic per seating position in order to have better control over levels. People's voices tend to vary quite a bit in level and this arrangement would give you maximum flexibility on the level of each speaker. If you can place them on the table it will allow you to be close to the source and pick up minimal surrounding noise and crosstalk.

This should give you an overall clean sound with less amplification and you pan them to a however wide a stereo image you want, either in post processing, or live on a mixer.

A compressor on each channel would make a great addition, a digital mixer would include this.